# Wrong hour in C++

Tags: c++, windows, timezone

```
// Simple program to get the date and time on Windows
//  It compiles and works fine but displays the wrong hour!


// Using Visual C++ 2008 Express on XP SP2
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


void main()
{
     SYSTEMTIME st;
     GetSystemTime(&st);

     cout << "Year : " << st.wYear << "\n";
     cout << "Month : " << st.wMonth << "\n";
     cout << "Day : " << st.wDay << "\n";

     // The following line displays the wrong hour, off by 4 hours. 
         // What gives?
     cout << "Hour : " << st.wHour << "\n";
     cout << "Minute : " << st.wMinute << "\n";
     cout << "Second : " << st.wSecond << "\n";
}

// TIA guys!
// -- Bert
```

Answer (score 19):

The time is in UTC according to the docs.  Link **[HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724390(VS.85).aspx)**

For local time you want **[GetLocalTime()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724338(VS.85).aspx)**

Answer (score 3):

`GetSystemTime()` returns the current time in UTC (see the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724390(VS.85).aspx)). If you're in EST (which is UTC-4 when DST is in affect), then it would return the current time + 4 hours.

Answer (score 1):

did you check to see if your time you get is in the correct timezone?

Windows has a [getlocaltime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724338(VS.85).aspx) function as well, that should return the proper time in your timezone.